# Spring Security Cookie is deleted when i enter Page

Tags: cookies, spring-security

i'm implementing a custom remember-me service to set a higher expire Date to the Remember Me Cookie of Spring.

RememberMeService extends TokenBasedRememberMeService

```
public RememberMeService() throws Exception {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void setCookie(String[] tokens, int maxAge, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Integer age = 60*60*24*365*10;
    String cookieValue = encodeCookie(tokens);
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(getCookieName(), cookieValue);
    cookie.setMaxAge(age);
    cookie.setPath(StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContextPath()) ? request.getContextPath() : "/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

spring-security.xml

```
<remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="yorpackage.RememberMeService">
    <beans:property name="key" value="YASUU_REM" />
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

All works fine, Cookie is set with a 10 Year Expire Date.
My Problem is, when i close the Browser and reopen it and surf to the site, the cookie is deleted and i cant get a auto-login to the page.

Any suggestions why this happens? Thanks 4 help

EDIT

After some investigation, i see, that spring finds the logged In User by the Cookie, loadUserByUsername() finds the correct User, but the Auto-Login failed and the Cookie is deleted. Why?

Comment: did find out a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom RememberMeService, just try this for setting your own expiration time:

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="key" value="YASUU_REM"/>
    <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="315360000"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And if you still need solve problem with deleting of cookie after success authentication, try to add the next:

```
<http>
    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="YASUU_REM" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a basicAuthenticationFilter you can do something like this.

```
<http entry-point-ref=...>
    ...
    <custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <custom-filter ref="rememberMeFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
    ...
</http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            ...
            <beans:ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"/>
            ...
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="key" value="${MY_KEY}"/>
</beans:bean>
```